# ERROR org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to conenct my java CRUD application with node red. But when I run the Java application I always get this error. I have tried to solve it but I can't.
This is the error:

```
2022-05-10 11:33:43.959  INFO 12192 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-05-10 11:33:43.969  INFO 12192 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-05-10 11:33:43.988 ERROR 12192 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/iratx/Documents/MU/2020/segundo%20semestre/PBL6Xabi/produktua/crudrest-api/muraicrud/target/classes/data.sql]: REPLACE INTO `roles` VALUES (1,'ADMIN'); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:610) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6] 
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) 
~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at com.example.CrudApplication.main(CrudApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]      
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/iratx/Documents/MU/2020/segundo%20semestre/PBL6Xabi/produktua/crudrest-api/muraicrud/target/classes/data.sql]: REPLACE INTO `roles` VALUES (1,'ADMIN'); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:622) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:202) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:91) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:38) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:111) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:762) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:646) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:601) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

I have tried t brose online but I can't fix it. I know that it says that it failed executing the SQL script but but I only have one table in my SQL with an roleId and a name. So I tried to pun INSERT INTO insead of Replace but I get the same error.

This is the sql statement:

```
create table roles(
id INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you supply the `CREATE TABLE` statement of the `roles` table? The reason bean creation fails is because you are trying to auto insert 2-columned records into that table which has less or more than 2 columns.

Comment: The error is pretty clear... `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` which only occurs if you have an insert into (or update) with a number of columns that doesn't mnatch the tables number of columns. So if you have 3 columns you should insert 3 values or specify which columns to insert.

Comment: create table roles(
roleId INT NOT NULL,
tipo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
) @Elias

Comment: Yes I know the error but the thing is that I have two colums and I want to insert to colums, so I don't know where is the error. This is the statement of the roles table:    create table roles(
roleId INT NOT NULL,
tipo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)@M.Deinum

Comment: It fails on the population... So without knowing/seeing whaty ou are trying to insert this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are connecting to the different database. In that database the `roles` table has more/less than 2 columns.

Instead of this line of code `REPLACE INTO roles VALUES (1,'ADMIN')` in `data.sql` file try specifying **exact** column names in your query:

```
REPLACE INTO roles(id,name) VALUES (1,'ADMIN');
```